# Xceed AvalonDock 3.2 DockWidth/Height has no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock, xceed

I'm using AvalonDock(Extended.Wpf.Toolkit, free version) in an app for my employer. Setting `DockWidth` or `DockHeight` in either `LayoutAnchorablePane` or `LayoutDocumentPane` has no(visible) effect. Instead, each pane occupies an equivalent amount of space relative to its siblings(they default to 1*).

They can be resized at runtime with the built-in splitters, but that doesn't help programmatically or at design time. I've used some workarounds such as:

- Setting `DockMinWidth`/`DockMaxWidth` to the
  same value, but obviously the splitters stop moving.
- Using reflection to brute-force change the size. This is quite fragile.

Both of which are dirty hacks that I'd like to avoid.

I'm aware that this was done in the past with `ResizingPanel`, but it's been long since removed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790527/3446285) for related information.

<s>I've yet to find the answer in the [documentation](https://12316-presscdn-0-94-pagely.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/webframe.html#Welcome.html) or the source code.</s>
See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501849/3446285).

Here's a [simplified example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4racqyi29a1asw6/XceedTest.zip?dl=0) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18890426/3446285) pointed me in the right direction.

The issue is indeed internal code. The following fixed it:

1. Add a flag to `ILayoutPositionableElement.cs`. I named it `ForceFixedDockSize`.
2. Implement it in `LayoutPositionableGroup.cs`.
3. Inside of every override of `OnFixChildrenDockLengths`, check if the flag is true before setting `DockWidth` or `DockHeight`.

I suspect the reason this behavior exists is to make default layouts look consistent. This change makes that behavior optional.

See [my fork](https://github.com/kobyduck/wpftoolkit/commits/master).

Comment: I ran into this issue again using AvalonDock v3.7 and this solution worked perfectly. Thank you. I'm surprised at how few questions there are about this behaviour.